# getting No value bound error while running junit

Tags: java, spring, junit

I  was tring to run the junit code but i am getting error saying Failed to load ApplicationContext  and in the caused by No value bound.
This is the error

```
Failed to load ApplicationContext
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:98)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$5(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.JupiterTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(JupiterTestDescriptor.java:215)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$6(ClassTestDescriptor.java:349)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassTestDescriptor.java:348)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassTestDescriptor.java:270)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$2(ClassTestDescriptor.java:259)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$3(ClassTestDescriptor.java:263)
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstanceProvider$4(ClassTestDescriptor.java:262)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:82)
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:59)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:95)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:91)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:60)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit5.runner.JUnit5TestReference.run(JUnit5TestReference.java:98)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
Caused by: java.util.NoSuchElementException: No value bound
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.bind.BindResult.get(BindResult.java:55)
    at his.common.config.AppPropertiesConfig.lambda$initAppConfig$0(AppPropertiesConfig.java:44)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:325)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:198)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:748)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:127)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractGenericContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractGenericContextLoader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.delegateLoading(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.loadContext(AbstractDelegatingSmartContextLoader.java:244)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:141)
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:90)
    ... 67 more
```

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@DirtiesContext(
        classMode = ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { AnaIitPh2ServiceTestApplication.class })
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AnaIitPh2ShowSeatMapTest {

    /** The logger instance for logging purpose */
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AnaIitPh2ShowSeatMapTest.class);

    /** gRPC server name */
    private String gRPCServerName;

    /** Constant for PORT */
    private static final int PORT = 8085;

    /** Constant for HOST */
    private static final String HOST = "localhost";


    /** Wire mock instance */
    private static WireMockServer server = new WireMockServer(PORT);

    /** Injecting mock of ANA IIT Connector service */
    @Autowired
    private AnaIitPh2AirGateCoreService anaIitPh2GateCoreService;

    /** API request headers */
    interface ApiHeaders {
        String CONTENT_TYPE = "Content-Type";
        String TEXT_XML = "text/xml";
        String SOAP_ACTION = "SoapAction";
        String Air_RetrieveSeatMap = "Air_RetrieveSeatMap";
    }

    /** WSDL End point path */
    interface EndpointPath {
        String SEATMAP_ENDPOINT_PATH = "/nodeA3.test.webservices.amadeus.com";
    }

    /** Response File names */
    interface ResponseFile {
        String Air_RetrieveSeatMap_SUCCESS = "AirRetrieveSeatMapSuccessReply";
    }

    /** Constant for xml extension. */
    private static final String XML = ".xml";

    /** Show seat map dummy data */
    interface ShowSeatMapData {
        String QUERY_ID = "d6779ec7b87a4";
        StringValue DEPARTURE_CODE = StringValue.of("HND");
        StringValue DEPARTURE_CODE_INVALID = StringValue.of("HNE");
        StringValue ARRIVAL_CODE = StringValue.of("MUC");
        StringValue ARRIVAL_CODE_1 = StringValue.of("SPK");
        StringValue AIR_LINE_CODE = StringValue.of("LH");
        StringValue FLIGHT_NUMBER = StringValue.of("4714");
        StringValue CLASS_OF_SERVICE = StringValue.of("M");
        StringValue CLASS_OF_SERVICE_1 = StringValue.of("Y");
        String CLIENT_ID = "1000";
        Date DEPARTURE_DATE = Date.newBuilder()
                .setYear(2023)
                .setMonth(11)
                .setDay(10)
                .build();
    }

    /**
     * A TestRule that can register gRPC resources and manages its automatic
     * release at the end of the test automatically
     */
    @Rule
    public final GrpcCleanupRule grpcCleanup = new GrpcCleanupRule();

    /**
     * Perform settings before the test execution starts
     */
    @BeforeEach
    public void setup() throws Exception {
        MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);
        /*
         * Get a unique name when establishing a server for service execution
         */
        gRPCServerName = InProcessServerBuilder.generateName();
        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessServerBuilder.forName(gRPCServerName).directExecutor().addService(ServerInterceptors.intercept(anaIitPh2GateCoreService, new GrpcLoggingInterceptor()))
                .build()
                .start());
        AnaIitPh2ServiceTestApplication.setupSecurityContext();
        // Wire mock server starting
        server.start();
        // Configuring the wire mock server in the defined host and port
        configureFor(HOST, PORT);
        // Stub for show seat API
        stubFor(post(urlPathMatching(EndpointPath.SEATMAP_ENDPOINT_PATH))
                .withHeader(ApiHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, WireMock.containing(ApiHeaders.TEXT_XML))
                .withHeader(ApiHeaders.SOAP_ACTION, WireMock.containing(ApiHeaders.Air_RetrieveSeatMap))
                .withRequestBody(WireMock.containing("Air_RetrieveSeatMap"))
                .willReturn(aResponse().withStatus(200)
                        .withBodyFile("showseatmap/AirRetrieveSeatMapSuccessReply.xml")));

    }
    /**
     * Perform any cleanup, after tests
     */
    @After
    public void cleanup() {
    }

    /**
     * Perform wiremock server stop
     */
    @AfterAll
    public static void tearDown() {
        if (server != null && server.isRunning()) {
            server.shutdown();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Test pattern : showseatmap <br>
     * Test case : Basic flow<br>
     * Expected result : Execute without error
     */
    @Test
    public void testShowSeatMapBasicFlow() {
        ShowSeatMapRq.Builder request = ShowSeatMapRq.newBuilder()
                .setQueryId(ShowSeatMapData.QUERY_ID)
                .setMetaData(ShowSeatMapRqMetaData.newBuilder().setClientId(ShowSeatMapData.CLIENT_ID))
                .setSegment(ShowSeatMapRqSegment.newBuilder()
                        .setDepartureCode(ShowSeatMapData.DEPARTURE_CODE)
                        .setArrivalCode(ShowSeatMapData.ARRIVAL_CODE)
                        .setDate(ShowSeatMapData.DEPARTURE_DATE)
                        .setAirlineCode(ShowSeatMapData.AIR_LINE_CODE)
                        .setFlightNumber(ShowSeatMapData.FLIGHT_NUMBER)
                        .setClassOfService(ShowSeatMapData.CLASS_OF_SERVICE));

        ShowSeatMapRs response = null;
        AirGateCoreServiceGrpc.AirGateCoreServiceBlockingStub blockingStub = AirGateCoreServiceGrpc
                .newBlockingStub(
                        grpcCleanup.register(InProcessChannelBuilder.forName(gRPCServerName).directExecutor().build()));
        try {
            // Execution of test method
            response = blockingStub.showSeatMap(request.build());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Assert.fail(e.getMessage());
        }
        assertTrue(response.getVacantInfoList().size() > 0);
    }

}
```

```yaml
server:
  port: 8090
grpc:
  port: 6503
  security:
    enabled: true
    oauth2:
      resourceserver:
        jwt:
          public-key-location: 'classpath:qa.air-gate.pub'
app:
  services:
    air-gate-core-service:
      endpoint: 'localhost:6565'
    air-ana-iit-ph2-connector-service:
      endpoint:
        schema_validation: false
        address: 'http://localhost:8085/nodeA3.test.webservices.amadeus.com'
        service_class: com.amadeus.xml.AmadeusWebServicesPT
        service_name: AmadeusWebServices
        endpoint_name: AmadeusWebServicesPort
      connection_timeout:
        default: 60000
        fare_masterpricetravelboardsearch: 60000
        fare_informativepricingwithoutpnr: 60000
        air_flightinfo: 60000
        air_sellfromrecommendation: 60000
        pnr_retrieve: 60000
        assignSeats: 60000
        service_bookpriceservice: 60000
        pnr_split: 60000
        to: 'https://nodeA3.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWAGTNH'
        username: WSHICCHA
        password: NVBVYWtWQWk
        agent_duty_code: SU
        pos_type: 1
        pseudo_city_code: TYOHI38AW
        requestor_type: U
        user_name_token: UsernameToken-1
      header_attributes:
        to: 'https://nodeA3.test.webservices.amadeus.com/1ASIWAGTNH'
        action_search_flight: 'http://webservices.amadeus.com/FMFTBQ_22_1_1A'
        action_retrieve_seat: 'http://webservices.amadeus.com/SMPREQ_22_1_1A'
        username: WSNH3HIS01
        password: q2eLoNJZ
        agent_duty_code: SU
        pos_type: 1
        pseudo_city_code: TYOHI38AW
        requestor_type: U
        user_name_token: UsernameToken-1
spring:
  datasource:
    url: 'jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/air_ana_iit?sslMode=disabled'
    username: root
    password: manager123
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    hikari:
      pool-name: ConnectionPool
      leakDetectionThreshold: 5000
      connection-test-query: SELECT 1
      minimum-idle: 2
      maximum-pool-size: 10
redis:
  host: localhost
  port: 6379
  enabled: true
  cache-expiry: 3600
  read-timeout: 100
  connection-timeout: 100
  key-version: V1_
scheduler:
  config:
    aide-cron:
      schedule: 0 40 22  * * *
      enabled: false
management:
  metrics.tags:
    environment: local
cache:
  configuration:
    key-slice-size: 6
```

Comment: having your `AppPropertiesConfig` source would help to tell what happens in its lambda line 44.  It would also be useful to know if there is an `application.yaml` just in `src/main/resources`, or if there's one in `src/test/resources` too (and what its content is if any). Last, the source of `AnaIitPh2AirGateCoreService` could be useful (as well as security configuration if you use method security in it).